# Swagger codegen Api returns null as string

Tags: null, swagger-codegen

when I run the swagger code generator, if api method returns string and data returned is null, it comes back as "null".
When I checked the Response body, it returns correctly as null.
But the swagger mapper converts this into a string "null".
Is there any configuration to map this as null?